# Se diz "com a frequência que" ou "com a frequência na qual"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática

Olá,

Estava escrevendo e surgiu esta dúvida. Como é correto escrever: "não tenho viajado **com a frequência que** gostaria" ou "não tenho viajado **com a frequência na qual** gostaria"? Ou ainda, ambas estão incorretas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Há duas hipóteses:

> (1) Não tenho viajado **com a frequência (de) que** gostaria.
>   (2) Não tenho viajado **com a frequência com que** gostaria (de viajar).

No primeiro caso, o argumento de *gostaria* é a frequência em si, no segundo é viajar (com dada frequência). Em (1), a preposição *de* é geralmente eliminada na oralidade.

**Na qual** não está correto; a preposição *em* não cabe em lado nenhum: dizemos *gostar **de*** e *viajar **com** dada frequência*.